# server IP address could not be found

Tags: .htaccess

i have uploaded file on [my domain name](http://poster.getrwanda.com/) file but when i try to visit it it show "This site can’t be reached
poster.getrwanda.com’s server IP address could not be found.
Search Google for poster get rwanda
ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED"

I have tried to make modification in file but it is not working

i asked my college and told me that i have to make some modification in .htaccess file but don't know what to put in.

Comment: you have misconfigured dns problem, not related to .htaccess. your provided domain cannot ping

Comment: the `getrwanda.com` domain exists and has valid NS entries, but the host `poster.getrwanda.com` doesn't have an entry and thus results in the name not being able to be resolved